# Pseudo element to cover 100% of body not match parent element

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm trying to get a pseudo element to cover 100% of the body/page not grab the height from the parent it's based off.

So I have something like:

```
   <body>
       <accordion></accordion>
       <div> Lots of content that extends a bit </div>
   </body>
```

You can see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robertaguilerajr/cvrhxm7p/1/) for an example of what I mean.

Basically, I want that shade to extend to the bottom of the page instead of just grabbing the parent's height.

I'm working on an angular project so that's why I'm little stuck with the markup and I need the parent item positioned absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS for the shade to cover all the page.

```css
 html {
  font-size: 100%;
 }
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 body {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
 }
 .container {
  
 }
 .accordion {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 88px;
  background:red;
 }
 .accordion:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 89px;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 10;
        overflow:visible;
 }
```

Change I made to your code is to remove position:absolute in accordion. Also remove padding or the container.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cvrhxm7p/8/

change `height: 100%;` to `height: 100vh;`

and if you dont want the page to scroll use this `height: calc(100vh - 89px);`
it will take out the height of your header.

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cvrhxm7p/9/

```
.accordion:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        height: calc(100vh - 89px);
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 89px;
        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround is just to set the height of accordion-after to 'px' measure instead of '%', like this

https://jsfiddle.net/cvrhxm7p/7/

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
.accordion {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 89px;
    background:red;
}
.accordion:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 89px;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `height: 100vh` instead of `100%`, (**vh** stands for viewport height, you can read more about those unit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)) (**See snippet 1**)

**SNIPPET 1**

```css
 html {
   font-size: 100%;
 }
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 body {
   background-color: #F9F9F9;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
 }
 .container {
   padding: 10px;
 }
 .accordion {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 88px;
   background: red;
 }
 .accordion:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   left: 0;
   top: 89px;
   visibility: visible;
   z-index: 10;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="accordion"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ipsam voluptas neque assumenda, saepe totam quis similique, nemo minima sequi, illum, officia veritatis provident soluta laborum esse alias dignissimos officiis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ipsam voluptas neque assumenda, saepe totam quis similique, nemo minima sequi, illum, officia veritatis provident soluta laborum esse alias dignissimos officiis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ipsam voluptas neque assumenda, saepe totam quis similique, nemo minima sequi, illum, officia veritatis provident soluta laborum esse alias dignissimos officiis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ipsam voluptas neque assumenda, saepe totam quis similique, nemo minima sequi, illum, officia veritatis provident soluta laborum esse alias dignissimos officiis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ipsam voluptas neque assumenda, saepe totam quis similique, nemo minima sequi, illum, officia veritatis provident soluta laborum esse alias dignissimos officiis.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```